# Confusion about move constructor, rvalue passed as func parameter, and unque_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, move-semantics

I have a question relevant to move semantics and unique pointer.

Suppose I want to use a manager class to handle a heap allocated integer, and

(1) I delete copy constructor of the manager class to make the handle unique.

(2) The demo function `consume` is used to takeover ownership of the manager.

I found the following 3 ways all compiled. I was wondering if they all achieve my goal. Are they roughly the same? Any subtle difference? Which is considered as recommended?

(I)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class intManager {
public:
    int* p;
    intManager() {
        cout << "constructor\n";
        p = new int;
    }
    ~intManager() {
        cout << "destructor\n";
        delete p;
    }
    intManager(intManager &src) = delete;
    intManager(intManager&& src) {
        cout << "move constructor\n";
        this->p = src.p;
        src.p = nullptr;
    }
};
void consume(intManager m) {
    return;
}
int main() {
    intManager m{};
    consume(move(m));
    return 0;
}
/*
The program prints:
-------------------
constructor
move constructor
destructor
destructor
*/
```

(II)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class intManager {
public:
    int* p;
    intManager() {
        cout << "constructor\n";
        p = new int;
    }
    intManager(intManager &src) = delete;
    ~intManager() {
        cout << "destructor\n";
        delete p;
    }
};
void consume(intManager &&m) {
    return;
}
int main() {
    intManager m{};
    consume(move(m));
    return 0;
}
/*
The program prints:
-------------------
constructor
destructor
*/
```

(III)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class intManager {
public:
    int* p;
    intManager() {
    cout << "constructor\n";
    p = new int;
    }
    intManager(intManager& src) = delete;
    ~intManager() {
    cout << "destructor\n";
    delete p;
    }
};
void consume(unique_ptr<intManager> m) {
    return;
}
int main() {
    unique_ptr<intManager> bar = make_unique<intManager>();
    consume(std::move(bar));
    return 0;
}
/*
The program prints:
-------------------
constructor
destructor
*/
```

Comment: In `(II)`, the ownership is not in fact transferred to `consume`. The heap-allocated `int` is destroyed when `main` returns, not when `consume` returns.

Comment: In `(III)`, you have an extra indirection and double the number of heap allocations. It's roughly equivalent to `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int>>`. There are still additional move constructors and destructors, you've just shifted them to a class that you haven't instrumented and so they don't get reflected in the output.